# singleton static method variables

Tags: java, methods, static, singleton, field

So I am trying to make a singleton object by using a private constructor and private static final new singleton class object in the field.

But I am confused as to what the methods will be. Will all methods needs to be static too? will all fields need to be static also?

Comment: The singleton pattern (an anti-pattern, really) is _extremely_ well documented numerous places on the web.  Do they not work for you in some way?  What is it about any/all of those samples that is confusing?

Comment: no need to be snarky jim. the ones i've come across are very short and have no fields or methods. merely just the skeleton to get the basic pattern across. if you're going to take the effort to type at all, you could have also just typed what the user "lexicore" did which was actually helpful, and required 35% less typing.

Comment: The point is that you are expected to do **serious** research prior posting questions. It is not *snarky* to remind you about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (single) instance of your singleton is already static so neither fields nor methods of a singleton class need to be static.

Answer (score 1):

Making `static` the members to manipulate your singleton makes no sense as the singleton pattern is designed to create and return a single instance of a class.

Suppose this code :

```
MySingleton.getInstance().foo();
```

If `foo()` was `static`, why invoking `getInstance()` before invoking foo() ? 
Instances are helpless to invoke static methods.
So this would be enough :

```
MySingleton.foo();
```

But in this case it would mean that the singleton instance doesn't need to be returned but is manipulated only by the class itself under the hood. 
It is not the intention of the singleton pattern wthat is ensuring that a class only has one instance an**d provide a global point of access to it**

Answer (score 0):

Technically you have two ways how to create a singelton.

Create a entirely static class with no available constructor

```
public final class StaticSingelton{

  private final static String readOnlyField = "readMe";
  private int static writeOnlyField = -1;
  private double static readAndWriteField = -1;

  private StaticSingelton(){
    throw new IllegalAccessException();
  }

  public final static String getReadOnlyField(){
  return readOnlyField;
  }
  public final static void setWriteOnlyField(final int value){
  writeOnlyField = value;
  }
  public final static double getReadAndWriteField(){
  return readAndWriteField;
  }
  public final static void setReadAndWriteField(final double value){
  readAndWriteField = value;
  }

}
```

Create a class which can only have one instance existing and allow access to it
public final class InstanceSingelton{

```
private final static InstanceSingelton instance = new InstanceSingelton();

  private final String readOnlyField = "readMe";
  private int writeOnlyField = -1;
  private double readAndWriteField = -1;

private InstanceSingelton(){
  if(instance != null){
    throw new IllegalAccessException();
  }
}

  public final static InstanceSingelton getInstance(){
     return instance;
  }

  public final String getReadOnlyField(){
  return readOnlyField;
  }
  public final void setWriteOnlyField(final int value){
  writeOnlyField = value;
  }
  public final double getReadAndWriteField(){
  return readAndWriteField;
  }
  public final void setReadAndWriteField(final double value){
  readAndWriteField = value;
  }
```

}

Unless you need an object instance for some reason personally i can't think of a difference in functionality.